# Jquery address plug and my existing script

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-address

I am trying to add address plugin to my existing script but I am experiencing problems.

Here is my jquery and html.  (noConflict is needed for other libraries included on this project)

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

$('.dk_movie_list .grid').hide().css('visibility','visible').address();

$('.dk_movie_list .grids .all').show();

$('.dk_movie_list .grids .all').jScrollPane({
    verticalDragMinHeight: 205,
    verticalDragMaxHeight: 205
});

// Display all on initial load
$('.dk_movie_list .grids .all').css({position:'absolute',display:'block'});

$('.dk_movie_list ul.nav li').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('btnSelect').siblings().removeClass('btnSelect');
    i = $(this).index();
    $('.dk_movie_list .grid:visible').fadeOut(400, function() {

        $('.dk_movie_list .grid:eq(' + i + ')').fadeIn(400).address();

        $('.dk_movie_list .grid').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 205,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 205
        });

    });

    $('.dk_movie_list .grid').jScrollPane({
        verticalDragMinHeight: 205,
        verticalDragMaxHeight: 205
    });

  });
});


 <ul class="nav">
                        <li class="all"><a class="btnSelect" rel="address:all">All</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Action-Adventure">Action-Adventure</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Comedy">Comedy</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Drama">Drama</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Documentary">Documentary</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Foreign">Foreign Films</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Horror">Horror</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Independent">Independent</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Family">Family</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Music">Music</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Romance">Romance</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:SciFi-Fantasy">SciFi-Fantasy</a></li>
                        <li><a rel="address:Suspense-Thriller">Suspense-Thriller</a></li>
                    </ul>
```

Just to confirm, I am including jquery.address-1.4.min.js after my script.js.  I also have jScrollPane library.

Currently, after i click each anchor, the path changes and i can also go BACK but if i copy past localhost:8888/#/Comedy it just defaults to the first menu item.

Thanks for suggestions or tips.

Comment: How should it? You need to check the hashtag on page reload, and if it got a hashtag, activate the function with that item. See http://www.brightcherry.co.uk/scribbles/2011/09/02/jquery-get-the-hash-tag-value-from-a-url/

Comment: Im sorry, I'm not sure how to add that bit of js.  Can you give more details. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

A page id (hashtag) dosen't indicate a click.

So if you enter localhost:8888/#Comedy or localhost:8888 it should make any difference.

But what you could do is check the hashtag on pageload and then do the script to threat it as a click.

So

```
if(window.location.hash) {
 //set the value as a variable, and remove the #
 var hash_value = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
 //i don't know your code so i can only simulate a click, you should instead do the real function
 $('a[rel$="'+hash_value+'"]').parent().click();
}
```

Im assuming you wan't the click on the LI tag, not A, since thats what you targeted with your JS.